# Run javascript function when ui-router state changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In a Angular App i am using ui-router to handle navigation etc.
In a separate script file, i have a function like so;

```
$(function () {
  function doSomething(){
    if ($('.thisclass').length) {
      $('.thisclass').css({ 'height': someHeight });
    }
  }
});
```

My problem is, that whenever the state changes, i want to run the above function. But as it is not part af any Angular function, i get an error when i reference it, as i cannot find it.

What should i be doing, instead of the above?

Comment: is there a reason that you wrap the function in `$()`?

Comment: None other, than it uses jQuery.

Comment: do you have access to `the $routeChangeStart`

Comment: Not within the above function where it currently sits. But i have within my Angular app i would presume?

Comment: try to create the function global and in the `$routrChageStart` you can call the the doSomething function. its quick and dirty but its should work

Comment: Write the function directly,i.e. instead of  `$(function(){ function doSomething() { /* ....... */  }    });` do `function doSomething() {/* ..... */}`. But it would pose a security risk! I would not suggest that, as @Zamboney mentioned, its quick and dirty ... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I would do.

> app.js

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app',[]);

    /* other code like configuration etc */
})();
```

> SomeService.js

```
(function(){    
    angular.module('app');
       .factory('someService',function(){
            return {
                     doSomething: function(){
                        $('.container-fluid').css('display', 'none');
                     }
                 };
       });
})();
```

> app.run.js

```
(function(){
  angular.module('app')
  //Inject your service here
  .run(function($rootScope,someService){ 
    //Look for successful state change.
    //For your ref. on other events.
    //https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
      //If you don't wanna create the service, you can directly write
      // your function here.
      someService.doSomething();
    });
  })
})();
```

Always wrap your angular code within [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) it wraps everything in closure and prevents leaks as well as provides a layer of security.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tested this, and it works. However, i missed something. I have calls to API's on most of my states. This API populates a list. Whenever this list changes, and are fully loaded, i want to calculate the height, to set the height of the element. It seems statChangeSuccess is loaded before this is the case. I guess i have to deal with the promise of some sort?

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not clear if I understand the flow properly. Would you be able to prepare a quick bare minimum js-fiddler or plunker ? It will make the process much faster! Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: For eg. When you say, "I have calls ...... API populates a list", my question is where do you store the list? in $rootScope? in some service?. If $rootScope then you could just do `$watchCollection` to look for changes and then trigger your code. There are many possible answers :( and I won't be able to help until I have some type of working code to play with !

Comment: I understand, but i think i got it working now with help from your example. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Use event.preventDefault() to prevent the transition from happening inside event function.

Answer (score 8):

Hello you can also add your **jquery code** into the `onEnter:function()` of your state , as `onEnter` is executed each time you change the state and a controller is loaded.

### example(a login state):

```
.state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/assets/modules/login/login.html',
                resolve: {
                    user: ['authService', '$q', function (authService, $q) {
                        if (authService.user) {
                            return $q.reject({authorized: true});
                        }
                    }]
                },
                onEnter: function () {
                    //i hide header tabs, you can add your code here
                    $('.container-fluid').css('display', 'none');
                },
                onExit: function () {
                   //onExit is executed when we leave that state and go to another
                }
            });
```

Hope helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the one controlling the state changes via $state.go() for example, you can amend it:

```
$state.go('somewhere', { 'place': 'somewhere' }).then(() => {
  // write your function here
});
```